# Why does Reese fall out of the sky?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

Why does Kyle Reese fall out of the sky onto the sidewalk when he travels back in time while all of the Terminators we see arriving in the franchise do so safely crouched in a stasis energy orb?

[image: Reese] [image: terminator]

Comment: Terminators, they know how to travel.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In *The Terminator* we saw the street where the Terminator arrived smoking like a skillet.  In *Terminator 2* we saw that the edges of objects intersecting the [Einstein-Rosen bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) glowing orange with heat.  In *Terminator 3* we saw such objects catch fire.  If Reese's arrival point were at street level he would have touched down in a red-hot pit, been horribly burned and likely been unable to complete his mission.  Having him arrive above ground and fall through the air was painful, but survivable.

Comment: NQ? Did the human get sent back without a firey spacemaking shield orb, or did his open above ground?

Comment: Near the beginning of the electrical storm we can see the wormhole open above ground with electrical arcs emanating from it.

Answer (score 6):

If we consider the background, the answer is fairly clear.  Because the earth is moving, time travel presents some challenges if one travels back to the same absolute position that you left, since the earth isn't going to be there any more.  I think we can assume both sides in the Terminator war have solved this problem.  The one that the humans don't seem to have solved is that the height of land can change over even a relatively short time given suitably large geographic events, or even non-natural intervention such as building raised banks.  Kyle, then, falls from the sky because the point from which he left was higher up in the time he left than in the present day.

As to why the Terminators travel in more style than the Resistance, the Resistance stole time travel tech from the Terminators.  The Terminators, being machines, have little need for a human understandable user interface, so to render Terminator tech useful, the Resistance would have had to code their own UI at the very least.   Given that they undoubtedly didn't understand the Terminator tech fully when they did so, their time travel devices are, quite unsurprisingly, less polished than those of the Terminators. Presumably they simply could not get the shield working or were not aware that it was even part of the machine, since they are unlikely to have observed an arrival from a working Terminator machine.

Answer (score 5):

In the film's [official novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Frakes_novel)) we see that the Tech-Com Tac Teams were just trying to make sure he'd materialize away from the ground to prevent insta-killing him.

> *He rubbed his arm unconsciously — a bloody scrape where he came down.
>   The techs had brought him in high.*
>
> ***With so little time to familiarize themselves with the
>   displacement-field equipment and its calibration, they must have erred
>   on the side of safety. Better than materializing knee-deep in
>   pavement. Right.***